# For loop in C++11 standard when passing to a function

Tags: c++, loops, c++11

Okay. So I'm currently reading a C++11 book, which told me to try out that thing:

```
int v[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto i : v)
{
    std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

And yay, it works! But now, when I have:

```
#include <iostream>


void write(int* v)
{
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int v[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    write(v);
}
```

I get this:
`main.cpp:6:19: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
     for (auto i : v)` and `main.cpp:6:19: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
     for (auto i : v)` + 'suggested alternatives' (bunch of lines with mingw paths)

Am I doing something wrong, or there's no way to use this loop outside the function, where a collection was defined?

Comment: I think you need to call `write(&v)` to specify the beginning of the collection

Comment: @pjcognetta, `&v` is a pointer to an array. Simply passing an array will decay it to an `int*`.

Comment: The range based for loop requires begin() and end() to expose the range to be processed.  Your write method takes an int* which does not satisfy this requirement.

Comment: So what should I pass/require in arguments?